# Error while trying to rename files in script and cmd line

Tags: perl, bash

```
$dir = "/home/naveen/mp3tag/testfolder";
opendir(DMP3, $dir) || die("Cannot open directory");
@files= readdir(DMP3;
foreach $f (@files)
{
  unless ( ($f eq ".") || ($f eq "..") )
  {
    $oldfile = $f;
    $newfile = $f;
    $newfile =~ s/ /_/g;
    print "Old file: $oldfile \t";
    print "New file: $newfile";
    print "\n";
    rename ("$oldfile", "$newfile") or warn "Couldn't rename $oldfile to $newfile !\n";
  } 
}
```

I'm writing a simple program to add underscores to an existing file and rename it. This is how far ive gotten with the code. However its not able to rename the file and gives me a warning and i'm not sure where the mistake is.

Also when i tried the same line on the cmd line I get the following error msg.

```
$ rename Jacques\ Greene\ -\ Clark\ \(Original\ Mix\).mp3 JG - C.mp3
Bareword "mp3" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 1) line 1.

$ rename Jacques\ Greene\ -\ Clark\ \(Original\ Mix\) JG - C
Can't locate object method "Original" via package "Mix" (perhaps you forgot to load "Mix"?) at (eval 1) line 1.
```

Comment: This program will not rename *a* file, it will rename *all* files in the directory. Also, "gives me a warning"... why would you not mention what the warning is?

Comment: Well the warning is the warn message that i get that its not able to rename. The other error message on the cmd line is listed under the cmd itself.

Comment: You should include `$!` in your warning to see what the actual error is.

Comment: There is an unmatched `(` in the line calling `readdir`. Please do not type in your code, just copy-paste it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to rename *all* the files in the directory, not just one file. The error could be a great many things, since you did not mention it, I could only guess.

`rename` is, as I recall, a bit wonky, and using `move` from [File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aCopy) is a safer bet. Also, you might want to avoid renaming directories. Using a more intuitive interface would probably not be a bad idea either.

One of your biggest mistakes is not using `use strict; use warnings;`. The amount of trouble you bring on yourself by leaving these out cannot be underestimated.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy qw(move);

for (@ARGV) {
    my $org = $_;
    tr/ /_/;
    move($org, $_) or warn "Couldn't move $org to $_: $!";
}
```

**Usage:**

```
perl script.pl /home/naveen/mp3tag/testfolder/*.mp3
```

So, as long as you give a proper glob as argument, your script will only affect those files. You can add more checks to make it stricter.

If that commandline attempt of yours is meant to be with using the tool from /usr/bin/rename, I would hazard a guess that your error can simply be avoided by using quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This working example might help

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my $dir = '/home/naveen/mp3tag/testfolder';
my @mp3s = glob ("$dir/*.mp3");

for my $mp3 (@mp3s) {
    my $new_mp3 = $mp3;
    $new_mp3 =~ s/\s/_/g;
    move($mp3, $new_mp3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `rename` in `/usr/bin`. If you want to call your program, choose a better name for it, or call it with full path specified.

But before you do, add at least the missing right bracket to `readdir`.

Comment: Sorry about wrong posting. I am actually doing it for all the files in the directory. Well the warning is the warn message that i get that its not able to rename. The other error message on the cmd line is listed under the cmd itself. I did my research on rename and almost everybody seems to get it right. For me its not working on the cmd line as well (see 2nd part of my code). Besides i even changed my file permissions to 777.

Comment: I probably was not clear enough: you are not calling your program, you are calling a different one.

Comment: The missing bracket was a typo. But I figured this out. I had to pass the path value along with the file to delete it. Its working and its all good now. Thanks.